# C string append

Tags: c, string, standards, append

I've got two C strings that I want to append and result should be assigned to an lhs variable. I saw a static initialization code like:

`char* out = "May God" "Bless You";`.

The output was really `"May GodBless You"` on printing out. I understand this result can be output of some undefined behaviour.

The code was actually in production and never gave wrong results. And it was not like we had such statements only at one place. It could be seen at multiple places of very much stable code and were used to form sql queries.

Does C standard allow such concatenation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed.

Extract from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation :

> Adjacent string literals are
>   concatenated at compile time; this
>   allows long strings to be split over
>   multiple lines, and also allows string
>   literals resulting from C preprocessor
>   defines and macros to be appended to
>   strings at compile time

Comment: const char* a = "May God"
const char* b = "Bless You" 

`const char* c = a b` Is this also possible?

Comment: No, only for string literals.

Comment: @Mayank: No. It's only for static initialization at compile time.

Comment: but `#define a "May God"`, `#define b "Bless You"`, `const char *c = a " " b;` is ok.

Comment: @Mayank: Also note that `a` and `b` aren't strings; they're pointers (except in pmg's example :)

Comment: @R..: `"May God"` isn't this a const char*. I used to think it is :(

Comment: @Mayank no, it's a string literal that is assignable to a `const char*`

Comment: string literals, in `C`, are of type `char[N]` where N is just large enough for all characters in the string literal **plus** the null terminator *(for comparison, in `C++`, string literals are of type `const char[N]`)*. You can point to them or, as a special case, use them to initialize arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. this concatenation is allowed in C, it is not undefined behavior.

Although I think it should produce "May GodBless You" (since there is no space in the quoted part)

Answer (score 2):

[The Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says

> 5.1.1.2 Translation phases
>
> 6.  Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

So, the Solaris compiler was doing the right thing.