# How to concatenate 2 strings when the first is defined in a preprocessor directive and the second is constant in C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

Here's what I have:

```
#define STRING "string 1"

string string2 = STRING + "string3";
```

This is wrong. What is the solution? Is the problem that `string2` must be constant or what else, and why?

Comment: You want `##` preprocessor operator?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977898/c-string-append

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define STRING "string 1"

std::string string2 = STRING "string3";
```

Concatenation of adjacent string litterals isn't a feature of the preprocessor, it is a feature of the C/C++

Comment: correct, but it would be good to also provide an explanation, wouldn't it?

Comment: `string =` is shorthand for the `string()` constructor which accepts a `char*` argument.  `STRING "string3"` is the juxtaposition of two `char*` values which, in C and C++, results in the values being concatenated.

Comment: thanks . I know this method. I tried it but before asking question i realized that i was printing the wrong variable STRING instead of string2 so it didnt work.:

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use operator + on two string literals, as this would effectively mean you are trying to add two char pointers.

There are two ways how to achieve what you want:

You can use runtime "string" concatenation (not preprocessor), but for this you need to construct a std::string from one of the string literals, so that the compiler knows what operator + overload to look for:

```
#define STRING "string 1"
string string2= string(STRING) + "string3"
```

Or, to use compile-time concatenation, keep both strings as string literals and just write then one after the other, the compiler will concatenate them:

```
#define STRING "string 1"
string string2= STRING "string3"
```

Or (to answer in C):

```
#define STRING "string 1"
const char string2[]= STRING "string3"
```

Comment: Not ideal since you're concatenating at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can imagine your `STRING` as a `const char *`. As such it has no notion of "how to add another const char* to myself".

For your case to work, you can either let the compiler concatenate them:

```
#define STRING "string 1"
std::string string2 = STRING "string3"
```

which works only for string literals (constant strings that are defined within your source code), or in general you'd have to make a `std::string` out of it first, which has an `operator+` overload, that allows you to add a C-String to it:

```
#define STRING "string 1"
std::string string2 = std::string(STRING) + "string3";
```

Comment: They are called string literals.